# Get random item from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I searched for it, but all the answers are pretty old so maybe there is a better way. I'm trying to get a random item from a Firebase DB which looks like this:

[image]

I want to get a random user, that is all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't look like you can do it without holding a list of users locally - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35086931/782358

Comment: You can try to retrieve all the userid in the form of an array. And use Math.random to pick randomly one of the users. If you want to use this method i can show you the implementation

Comment: @UmarZaii I would really apreciate that!

Comment: Please specify your question further: what is the structure of your Firebase database exactly? And what needs to be randomized exactly? Your code example is just a short HTML snippet, I'm wondering how it relates to your question exactly.

Comment: @ElmarJansen I've edited the question to show the database structure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edit: seems that this solution does not work, as "limitToFirst" and "limitToLast" are not allowed to be used together. For reference, this was the proposed (not working) solution, assuming you know the number of users:

```
const numberOfUsers = 15;
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfUsers);

var ref = firebase.database().ref('companies/01/users');

ref.limitToFirst(randomIndex).limitToLast(1).once('value').then(snapshot =>
{
    var user = snapshot.val();
    // do something with the user data
});
```

If you don't know how many children there are (or have a children list stored somewhere else), there is no direct way to solve this problem without first receiving all children in the tree. See [In Firebase, is there a way to get the number of children of a node without loading all the node data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148803/in-firebase-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-number-of-children-of-a-node-without-load) for more info.

Comment: The best approach to knowing how many users there are would probably be using Googles Cloud Functions to create a script to increment a count field for your table.

Comment: For me this did not work, I get an error saying that you can't use `limitToFirst` and `limitToLast` together. The solution below is better since you won't have to keep a count of the items (which is actually tricky in Firebase too).

Comment: Mee too, I got the same erro

Comment: Same as me currently. Also searching for a quick and easy answer but this was to easy to be true.

Answer (score 13):

I had to resolve the same problem, I added a random number from 0 to 1 to all records to finally filter by **startAt** and **limitToFirst** to 1.

Example:
https://your-project-qwert.firebaseio.com/example.json?orderBy="random"&limitToFirst=1&startAt=0.84

Comment: This works. The currently accepted answer does not work (anymore?) since it's not allowed to use limitToFirst and limitToLast together. Also keeping a count of an array is not always scalable. his should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Additional note: you first have to request what is the highest random number in the list (using `orderByxxx.limitToLast(1)`) to make sure you bound your random number properly using `var rand = Math.random() * highestValue;`

Comment: I agree (poster of accepted answer). I tried the solution back then, don't know why it doesn't work any more. Regardless, this solution is much more elegant and useful. Does anyone know whether I can do something to help making this the accepted answer? :)

Comment: Only the person who asked the question can change the accepted answer (I think).

Comment: If the user count is not large, queries similar to startAt=0.84... may not return a node. To ensure select one always, I always select node with orderByxxx.limitToLast(1) and then update the selected nodes random field in order to throw it a rondom place in the ordered list.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for the same function, now I guess it can be done with the new released *Cloud Firestore*, but I'm looking for a simple solution.

btw. the neat feature of *limitToFirst* + *limitToLast* **does not work**, at least not in javascript (web).

The best I can come up with (if the key index "time-random" is not enough) are:

> If you only need the data random once (my situation, a deck of random cards):

add a value with Math.random() and orderByChild() on that number, remove keys or use startAt() with the last used key as parameter.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('companies/01/users').push();
var randomValue = Math.random();
ref.update({ ..., 'r': randomValue });

...

var ref = firebase.database().ref('companies/01/users')
ref.orderByChild('r').limitToFirst(1).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var data = snapshot.val()
  ...
  snapshot.remove()
});
```

> If the data should be used the get a random element many times a known index is needed.

a known numbered index can be added

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('companies/01/users').push();
ref.update({ ..., 'r': '0001' });

...

var ref = firebase.database().ref('companies/01/users')
ref.orderByChild('r').limitToLast(1).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var totalIndex = Object.values(snapshot.val())[0].r;
});
var randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalIndex);
ref.orderByChild('r').equalTo(randomValue).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var data = snapshot.val()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const numberOfUsers = 15;
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfUsers);
var ref = firebase.database().ref('companies/01/users');
ref.startAt(randomIndex).limit(numberOfUsers).once('value').then(snapshot =>
{
    var user = snapshot.val();
    // do something with the user data
});
```

Answer (score -1):

First you have retrieve all the userid from the firebase.

Then declare an array that stores all the userid in it. Below shows on how to store the userId.

```
var arr = new Array();
// or var arr = [];
arr.push('user001');
arr.push('user002');
```

Next you have to select randomly from one of the userId.

```
var item = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
// item is randomly picked userId
```

I'm sorry because i didn't completely show you on how the implementation works as I don't use javascript much.

Basically this is how the logic works. I hope it helps you :D

Comment: The problem is this isn't scalable. It's not efficient to load the entire index, just to pick one at random. Especially when the records you're looking at are larger than the user table.