# Retrieve random key from firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I face the problem that I have a list of keys inside my firebase database and I want to retrieve one random key out of it, without downloading all keys and selecting one in my own app. Downloading all keys with for example `.once()` is a big no go, especialy because I may up end with 10.000+ keys in the future and I dont want my firebase bills to explode, Im still a student with no budget at all.

I already researched this topic and found [following answer for my question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45148511/10900354)

The problem with this is, that I can not use `limitToFirst()` and also `limitToLast()` in the same query, else I get following error:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Query.limitToLast: Limit was
> already set (by another call to limit, limitToFirst, or limitToLast).]

Also other people face the same problem like me and I generaly see that this question always gets much views but rather poor answers which are, like apperently in the case I mentioned earlier outdated, or just not for usage in Javascript and React-Native.

Additional informations: I have a counter for my keys so I know at every time how many keys are stored inside my database. Following picture shows my database entirely:
[image]

This is the part of my code which shows the mentioned error:

```
const numberOfUsers = await firebase.database().ref("usercounter").once("value").then(snapshot => {
            return(snapshot.val()); //retrieve numbers of users from "usercounter"
        });
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfUsers) + 1; //"generating random number, excluding 0"
        var ref = firebase.database().ref('users'); //ref to my users keys
        await ref.limitToFirst(randomIndex).limitToLast(1).once('value').then(DataSnapshot =>
            {
                //This is the query that does not work at all. 
                console.log(DataSnapshot.val())
               
            });
```

Incase there is a way to overcome that problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve that problem this way:

Create for each list element a value with the field name `id` or some other you want. It should be a simple integer. Idealy incrementaly growing with the list. You could use the counter to increase the value each time you add an element.

When trying to get a random element from the list first get a random integer between 0 and the total count of all elements. Then use this query to get a single random element:

```js
firebase.database().ref("users").orderByChild("id").startAt(randomNumber).limitToFirst(1);
```

Even if you don't hit the `id` with the `randomNumber` you would the neareas next element. This should be able to scale to any size.

The most diffictult part would be to optain the `id` incrementaly without repeating them. I would use for that an cloud function that does it when an item is added. Even a combination with the counter would be interesting.

Comment: Tried it out, and it works perfectly. Not only the problem with downloading too much data is solved, Im getting the key which I asked for and also the child values nested below it which is totaly fine for my purpose. This solution should also apply to the linked example I shared above in my question.

I dont think the Cloud Functions are necessary here because when I create a new user (thats what those IDs are for) I automaticly raise the total counter of all users. When its raised I can obtain it again and give the new list element a id with ```totalusers+1```.

Mission accomplished.

Comment: the only thing thats somehow strange is a warning that pops off: ```FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. ``` Do you consider this a threat to my app?

Comment: I searched up this warning and now added ".indexOn": "counter" in my security rules, this diabled the little warning and now its everything perfect.

Comment: Sorry for the late respnse. Yes just adding an index for the 'id' field will solve that warning problem. Great to hear that it worked out 